# can foreach be filtered by id from foreign key?

Tags: laravel

So this is my code and my table

```
<li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
  <a class="active show" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#menu-rice" aria-selected="false "role="tab">                
    <div>
       <i class="fa-solid fa-bowl-rice"></i>
       <h6>Rice</h6>
     </div>
   </a>
</li>
........

<div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="menu-rice" role="tabpanel">
  <div class="tab-header text-center">
    <h3>Rice</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    @foreach ($ar_menu as $row)
      <div class="col-lg-6 menu-item">
        @empty($row->foto)
          <img src="{{ url('/public/assets/img/menu/placeholder.jpg') }}"alt="Menu" class="menu-img">
        @else
          <img src="{{ url('/public/assets/img/menu')}}/{{$row->foto}}"alt="Menu" class="menu-img">
        @endempty
        <div class="menu-content"> 
          <a href="#">{{ $row->nama }}</a><span>{{ $row->harga }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-ingredients ps-2">
          {{ $row->ket }}
        </div>
      </div>
    @endforeach
  </div>
```

From Menu Table:

| id | id_kategori | nama | harga | ket | foto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Fried Rice | 40000 |  |  |
| 2 | 2 | Chicken Buttermilk | 40000 |  |  |

From Kategori Table:

| id | nama |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | rice |
| 2 | chicken |

So I want to filter a menu by it's category from menu table, so I want when id_kategori = 1 from menu tables it will show #menu-rice from code above, but I don't know how to make it :/ Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by multiple way. Here is one example

first add filter

```
<form action="{{url()->current()}}">
<select name="category_id" onchange="this.form.submit()">
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
</form>
```

Then receive the category_id in controller and change the query like this

```
Menu::whereCategoryId($request->category_id)->get();
```

Return the result to view and show in loop.